# How to assign printing value of Serial.println(flon,6); to a variable?

Tags: gps, arduino

I'm trying to get the GPS values from GPS module in my arduino board.

```
gps.f_get_position(&flat, &flon, &age);
```

from above code I can get the lat and lon but when I access `flat` it contains only a value with 2 floating point numbers ex - 6.97 But when I use `Serial.println(flan,6);` this displays exact values of my GPS location. But I can't get those values into a variable. How can I get those values into a variable ?

Comment: Learn C to see that C is not Arduino is not C!

Comment: What type are `flat` and `flon`? `float`s? Anyway with the `println` function you just print it, so the value is correct. How can you say that the variable does not hold the correct data?

Comment: How do you access ` flat` to check its value ?

Comment: " but when I access `flat` " what do you mean? Post some code you tried